# Permanently saving changes to $PATH

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew, path

I have ruby and homebrew running for a while and I'm starting to play with Bash. I have encountered a problem with my PATH variable as echo'd:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin??n’export
```

As you can see, there is both redundancy and junk at the end int he form of illegal characters (causing a host of other issues).
I can change the PATH with

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"
```

which does indeed return the desired PATH when echo'd:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

But I can't figure out for the life of me how to save the PATH so that it doesn't reset on reopening. I don't need to add paths. I just want to make this the new value of that variable. Please, how can I make this change permanent?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add your **export PATH...** line in your **bash_profile** file. This file is run every time you start terminal and will modify your PATH variable as you want. You can open/edit this from anywhere in terminal using

```
 open ~/.bash_profile
```

You probably also want to check that there are no conflicting **export PATH...** statements that overwrite each other or something.

Comment: Okay, I found this, and it did indeed work, so I'm all set on that front, but since that file was originally empty, where is the file that stored the original statement? Can the original or the default be edited in any way? I assume so because macports managed to do so which is what messed it up in the first pace. Or do we not do follow-up questions here?

Either way, thank you for the response!

Comment: Hmm sorry, that one is a little bit out of my depth, I did have a quick search but couldn't quite pin down where the default variables come from. I'll leave that for someone else. Also, it *might* be a good idea splitting it off into a separate question, its more likely to elicit more responses and makes it easier for people searching for the same question in the future. (I don't actually know what the official policy is on follow-ups though)

Comment: Check `.profile`.

Comment: Or `grep -r "export PATH" /` ;)

Comment: @cubuspl42 is correct in that it may be set in your `.profile`. It can also be set (system wide)  in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`, though it isn't set there by default.  There is also the file `/etc/paths` which contains a list of directories to include in $PATH, and the directory `/etc/paths.d` which includes further customisations.